# Stack Overflow 503 errors while browsing

Tags: bug

I have been getting random 503 errors today. I'm in the US, so the other questions about 503 errors aren't relevant. What could be causing this, and is there anything I can do to fix it?

I am only going through the site, not trying to post or anything like that. I have never had this issue before today.

Comment: Confirmed - browsing from Israel.

Comment: Me too from the UK - also getting the maintenance page every now and again as well. Superuser appears ok, but Serverfault is not loading at all.

Comment: We're investigating this right now, appears to be a bad build

Comment: China, same issue.

Comment: VPN exiting in Switzerland, same. If you turn it off for an hour that would be good though, it'd help me get some work done.

Comment: @halfer depends what time zone your in ;) my real working day just ended here so was going to put a couple of hrs in here but I guess that means it time for food/drink and try again later.

Comment: Mr. Craver broke it. Says it'll be up in a few minutes. https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1006576884270927873

Comment: Heh @user3788685, yeah: I meant turn it back on again for people who really need it for their work `:-)`.

Comment: @vcsjones I wonder if there's a way to automatically point people to his Twitter account when posting about Stack Exchange servers.

Comment: Possible cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311167/unable-to-connect-to-multiple-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: There was some outage today, it was explained on the SE twitter, it was only a minor outage, but it is obviously very ontopic on the SO. I have no idea, what could have been in the mind of the first VtC voter.

Comment: @peterh Hi, since you said you don't know what was on my mind I'll explain. The situation no longest exists, therefore this close reason applies _"The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete**. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question."_ And I'm not sure why you singled me out since i was not alone in voting to close

Comment: @j08691 I think you are right in the literal interpretation. However, this close reason targets the essentially irreproducible problems (for example: "yesterday my firefox flashed as I opened the SO" or similar), and not the admittedly existed (and solved) ones. The rationale: such problem reports as in the example are obviously unwanted here. While reporting problems about outages, explaining their reasons have a positive side to the transparency and thus they are wanted and useful.

Comment: Just add status-resolved tag instead of closing...? It's on-topic, but resolved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue has been resolved - a build went out with some bad async code that was causing a crash of a low-level IIS process.

Comment: Ewwww IIS......

Comment: @user3788685 please don't

Answer (score 3):

Reason for errors as written by Nick Craver:

> The cause is not immediate apparent. An Http lib switch missed an init call from a bad rebase. This only showed after a 30 min cache expired. The throw from an async background method in an unobserved continuation somehow took out the pool. Still digging into how it happened.

Source: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1006583615382310912

**EDIT:**
If you want to know more about the bug (from a recent tweet):

> I now have a repro of the conditions involved. It happens in a stale background async fetch on a thread (to not block user pages) when an async handler itself throws. This bug has been laying dormant, but combined with a bad deploy (that thew) it was catastrophically exposed.

Follow this thread to see regular updates: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1006593191443947520

Comment: Who is Nick Kraver? And when was he [knighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Bachelor)?

Comment: Edited to correct the name, my apologies..

Comment: Well Nick's twitter account is sort of an alternative to @stackstatus . You can find more information about him at his twitter account: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver